# React Native: How to change parent component's state from child component and re-render parent?

Tags: react-native

I have "RootComponent" which has a state **isLoggedIn** and loads **Login** and **Home** as:

```
..
..
switch (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
case 'true':
return (
<Home />
);

case 'false':
return (
<Login />
);

default:
return <Spinner size='large' color='red' />; 
}
...
```

In **Login** I want to change **isLoggedIn** state when login button is pressed and rerender to **Home** screen. Without using Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent component should be passing the props to both the Login and Home component. What you need is a method in the parent component which updates the state of the parent component. The method will be passed down as a prop to Login component.

Your root component should look something like this

```
handleClick() { this.setState({isLoggedIn: true}); }
render() { 
   return ( 
      {!this.state.isLoggedIn && <Login handleClick={this.handleClick}/>} 
      {this.state.isLoggedIn && <Home />
    );}
```

Your Login component

```
render() { return (<Button
onPress={this.props.handleClick}
title="Press Me"
/>;}
```

Flow - 
When user clicks on the button, the `handleClick` function will be called which is passed down as props. So, the method in the parent component will be executed and this will update the state `isLoggedIn`. Once the state is updated, the new values will be passed down to the Login and Home component, and they will treat it as updated props and hence will re-render

Comment: Thanks a bunch !! got It working. But now I'm getting a warning.
**Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.**

Comment: My guess is you are probably doing some `setState({})` functionality in Login component, which still occurs after you have unmounted the same component.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass a function to the login component that once logged in will be called and update the state of the parent:

```
...
switch (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
  case 'true':
    return (
      <Home />
    );

  case 'false':
    return (
    <Login updateLoginState={() => this.setState(state => ({ isLoggedIn: 'true'}))} />
    );

  default:
    return <Spinner size='large' color='red' />; 
}
...
```

and in your Login component you simply call `this.props.updateLoginState()` at the point that the login process is finished

Although I'm not sure how you're reach the spinner state...

Comment: Thank you! isLoggedIn set to null first. Which is updated by getting values from AsyncStorage

Comment: Ah so eventually this component updates it's own state to get to the logged in page